# jQuery newsTicker pause on mousehover

Tags: php, jquery

I had already made a newsTicker in jQuery but need to pause on hover. What I have done so far follows:

a .php file `newsticker.php`

```
<html>
<head> <script src="include jquery files"> </script></head>

    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="head" class="block"></div>

        <div id="content">
        <div id="info" class="block">
            <ul id="ticker">
                <li>
                    <span>Title Lorem Ipsum 1</span>
                    <a href="#">some text that will be shown here.need to pause the 
                                news on mouse hover and showing the news in different                   box</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span>Title Lorem Ipsum 2</span>
                    <a href="#">some text that will be shown here.need to pause the 
                                news on mouse hover and showing the news in different box</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body></html>
```

jQuery file common.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ticker = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#ticker li:first').animate({
                marginTop: '-120px'},
                800,
                function() {
                    $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style');
                });
            ticker();
        }, 4000);
    };
    ticker();
});
```

How can I pause the news and show in different div box like found in [here](http://stepup.net.in) when mouse hovers?

run jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anonghost1987/se4yv/2/)

Comment: please add a plunkr or jsfiddle. Thanks

Comment: @Robin my jsfiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anonghost1987/se4yv/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, there is a small bug inside. Then we use small trick.

```
var ticker = function()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ticker li:first:not(.stop)').animate( {marginTop: '-120px'}, 800, function()
        {
           var me = $(this);        

           me
            .clone(true)
            .appendTo('ul#ticker')
            .removeAttr('style')

           me.remove(); 
        });                                                
        ticker();
    }, 4000);
};

ticker();

// simply toggle class on hover
// animation will not run with `li` having this class

$('#ticker li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('stop')
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('stop')
});
```

Comment: almost tried every if and buts but could not really make it happen.u can see my code in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anonghost1987/se4yv/2/)